# Can we put up a blanket disclaimer of legal advice so that no answer, regardless of its source, can be taken as legal advice?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed a couple of bios with disclaimers to the effect that "no answer offered on this site is legal advice - consult an attorney - etc."

I am in the same or similar circumstance as some others with lots of **practical** experience in the world of patents or patent litigation, but no basis for offering **legal** advice.  Actually, I may be in worse shape that some others because I am a **licensed attorney** - but my license status is "inactive," meaning that I do not (and am not permitted to) practice law.  Ever.

Can we put up a prohibition on legal advice or a universal disclaimer?  Failing that, how about a setting to automatically apply a [not legal advice] tag for those of us who may be at risk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is such a disclaimer in the [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#get-legal-advice) already:

> #### Can I get legal advice or official government positions here?
>
> No. This website does not provide legal advice and is not an official government site. While our users may well be lawyers, they are not your lawyers, and their posts are not legal advice.  Similarly, while our users may well be government officials, they are here to educate the public and provide citizens a voice, not to change or establish the government’s position on any issue.

Comment: can't remember if this is clearly shown on registering, but i think putting this (or a shorter version) front and center when signing up would go a long way. even if it just is a single sentence and links to the FAQ.